# Adapting std::swap interface to swap n bytes

Tags: c++, swap

I have a C function to swap an arbitrary number of bytes:

```
void my_swap(void* a, void* b, long n);
```

I've done a little benckmark with several types and I've seen that `std::swap` outperform `my_swap`.

So, I'd like to wrap `std::swap` with `my_swap` interface, but I can't figure out how to tell `std::swap` to behave as if it was swapping two variables of a type `T`, for which `sizeof(T)==n`.

Can anybody wrap `std::swap` in a function with same signature (and same semantic, of course) as `my_swap`?

Comment: When you have `std::swap` which is type safe, why use `my_swap` which throws away type information?

Comment: @NickyC Because I have a lot of old code that I cannot break.

Comment: You can't if you don't know the value of `n` at compile time. But you can use `std::swap_ranges` if you reinterpret cast `a` and `b` to `char*`.

Comment: To clarify, does `my_swap` swaps two arrays of things, or just two objects?

Comment: @NickyC my_swap copies n bytes starting from b in a temp buffer, then n bytes starting from a to b, then n bytes from the temp buffer to a.

Comment: How do you create a temporary buffer? You know, just additionally, std::swap usually uses local variable to store the value (although some objects in C++ may be value types with hidden dynamic object inside); if you allocate the memory dynamically, you lose extra power.

Comment: A question about performance without the tested code, seriously?

Comment: @curiousguy A question about performance? Are you sure? I mean: are you sure that you even read the question? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible because std::swap must know exactly the type of the passed variables.

There may be several reasons as to why your `my_swap` is slower than `std::swap`, like:

- Your function transfers byte-by-byte, which usually results in being 4* (or more) slower than doing the same operation done on ints
- The compiler generates slower code because it cannot be sure that these two `void*` variables point to an "unaliased" memory (in particular, that the operation you're going to do with the pointed memory will not reach the area of one that may overlap with the other). Compilers are not allowed to generate fast code for that cases because in case of overlaps it will result in wrong data operation.

This is why it is impossible to write an implementation of `my_swap` that would be that fast as `std::swap` because this `void*` as argument is the reason.